# Using a existing file in the python console

Tags: python, macos, file, console

Running Python 3.9.6 on Terminal (Mac).

I can't seem to figure out how to use an existing file from the python console.
My existing file is named `sim.txt`.

`>>> wv.evaluate_word_pairs("sim.txt")`

Gets me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sim.txt'`.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: have you tried using ls to list what files are in the directory? Is the sim.txt file in the same place as the place your are running the python script?

Comment: Your code is assuming `sim.txt` is in the current working directory (cwd). You can see what that is via `import os` followed by `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: @Nhyi: One cannot run `ls` directly from the Python console. You could get the equivalent via `os.listdir('.')` after an `import os`.

Comment: Ah my bad, yeah my next idea was to say use the os module. Cheers for clarifying on my end!

Comment: If the file is not in the current working directory, you can either change the cwd via `os.chdir()` or pass the full path to the file when calling the function: i.e. `>>> wv.evaluate_word_pairs("full/path/to/sim.txt")`.

Comment: ok its all good now. Thanks guys